# How to Model Inheritance

Tags: database-design, data-modeling, multiple-inheritance, class-diagram, erd

I am a bit confused in choosing an approach to model the following relationships.

Scenario:

1. The system has a User.
2. The User can perform 2 functions :

   - He Can be a normal User who can buy products listed on the website.
   - He Can Subscribe to Sell Products on the website.
   - He Can Subscribe for the Delivery Service to Delivery his orders placed
     from the website
   - He can Subscribe for Both i.e. Sell Products as well as subscribe for
     Delivery Service.

**How can i model the user who can do both the functions of a seller as well as place delivery requests.**

```
                               User
                                 |
                                 |
         _________________________________________________
        |                                                 |
      Seller (ONLY)                                   Delivery (ONLY)

                      **SELLER AND DELIVERY**
```

Comment: Don't use inheritance here. The relationships are not stable (could be seller or buyer or both or neither). Use composition.

Comment: @Neil McGuigan: why should this dynamism be an argument against using subtyping/inheritance? Clearly, both `Seller` and `DeliverySubscriber` are subtypes of `User`.

Comment: @gwag No, they are not subtypes of User. They are Roles that a User can play. Is a teacher a subtype of person? Is a student a subtype of person? What if a teacher takes a class? Multiple inheritance?

Comment: @Neil McGuigan: Yes a teacher is a person, and a student is a person (and roles are, indeed, special kinds of subclasses). If a teacher takes a class, she is both a teacher and a student. Logically/conceptually, there is no problem with multiple inheritance. If you have a problem with it because your favorite programming languages doesn't support it (well), this is not a good reason to reject it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options how to implement the class hierarchy formed by `Seller` and `DeliverySubscriber` being subtypes of `User`. If your subclasses/subtables do not have many additional properties/columns, one would normally use the ***Single Table Inheritance*** approach with just one table `User` and a `type` (or `category`) column for discriminating between users who are sellers and users who are delivery subscribers. Otherwise, if there are many additional properties/columns, it's better to use the ***Joined Table Inheritance*** approach, where subtables (representing subclasses) are joined to their supertable via their primary key being also a foreign key referencing the supertable. You can read more about these two forms of implementing class hierarchies with tables in my book chapter [Subtyping and Inheritance](http://oxygen.informatik.tu-cottbus.de/webeng/JsFrontendApp/complete-tutorial.html#d5e3708).

Comment: I have additional columns as well as subscription plans for both the user types. I feel its better to use Joined Table Inheritance.

Answer (score 2):

I would just use 3 tables: User, UserSeller, UserDelivery with a field UserType in User table to indicate which case applies. The three tables hare a common primary key.

Comment: How to Identify the user who has both seller and delivery cap

Comment: The UserType field would take values 0-Seller; 1-Delivery; 2-SellerDelivery.

Comment: You forgot to explain that the primary keys of your UserSeller and UserDelivery tables should also be foreign keys referencing User. This is the Joined Table Inheritance pattern, as explained in my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

assuming the person must be a user and can also be a Seller or Delivery or both - 
the relationship should be - User ------ Seller - 1:1 (one to one - any user can be one seller and every seller must be a user). the same goes to Delivery (a user can sign for delivery and a delivery must be a user).

in c# - this will mean than the seller class is derived from user, same as the delivery class.

in DB  - the dilevery and Seller tables will hold a FK to a Users PK which will also be their primary key.

Comment: How to Identify the user who has both seller and delivery cap

Comment: query the db after doing a join on the tables (after the join select the users who's id appears on both the tables)

Comment: According to your proposal, a seller would/could be linked to several users. That doesn't make sense. Any seller is a user, but (s)he is not many users.

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in just ER modeling, look into "generalization/specialization".

If you are interested in table design, take a look at the questions and the tag wiki for these two tags:

[single-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/single-table-inheritance)
[class-table-inheritance](/questions/tagged/class-table-inheritance)

One of these two should fit your case.